# Count the frequencies of all space and characters in the text file

Tags: java, file, input, output, text-files

I have some questions about a text file :

1. How can I count and sort the frequencies of characters, space, ('.'operator) and number of words in text file without HashMap .

I tried to solve this by:

```
public class Aaasssssss {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file1 = new File("input.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file1));
        System.out.println("Letter Frequency");

        int nextChar;
        char ch;

        int[] count = new int[30];

        while ((nextChar = in.read()) != -1) {

            ch = ((char) nextChar);
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
                count[ch - 'a']++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%c %d", i + 'A' , count[i]);
            System.out.println( "");
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

I use array [30] for 26 letter , 1 for (. operator ) , 1 for space , 1 for number of word and 1 for number of charter

Comment: your code is fine if you want to count occurance only from `a` to `z`, but you haven't write any logic for counting `.`, space.

Comment: `count = new int[128]` and check that `ch < 128`. That is the 7 bits ASCII range.

Comment: how can I sort this code frequencies from bigger to smaller ? for example number of character of letter ' A ' = 4 and ' B ' = 7 and I want put  letter ' B' first cause bigger than letter ' A '